Cognito "Authorizer" element not appearing in RequestContext in a Lambda triggered via API Gateway
Possibly inexperience with the AWS/Amplify side: I have an app built using Amplify, where I have a userbase controlled with Cognito. In my Cognito user pool I have created a custom attribute, that I want to pass to my API to be used in custom logic. I have access to that custom attribute in the front-end, but for security concerns I do not want to expose it there.
In my app I am calling my resource in my API Gateway:
let restCall = post({
        apiName: MY_API_NAME,
        path: "/MY_PATH",
        options: {body : parameters},
        headers: {"Authorization": "user_ID_Token"}
    });

    const {body} = await restCall.response;

I am using my Cognito Pool as an authorizer for that resource. "Authorization" is the authentication header I've defined as per this guide, and "user_ID_Token" is the attribute I get when calling "fetchAuthSession().tokens.idToken" which I (believe) am using to authorize the call.
This then calls my lambda that is triggered via this request
In it, I have the below code the logs out the request context:
app.post('/MY_PATH', async function(req, res) {

console.log(`requestContext ${JSON.stringify(req.apiGateway)}`);
console.log(`requestContext ${JSON.stringify(req.apiGateway.event.requestContext)}`);

From other resources I have seen, I would expect the "req.apiGateway.event.requestContext" to contain an "authorizer" object, under which would be a "claims" object that then contains details of my user, including attributes. I'm aware there are some steps required to get the specific custom attributes I want in there, but my issue is that there is no authorizer object in the first place! Below is an extract from a recent log in cloudwatch for that lmabda
"requestContext": {
            "resourceId": "xxx",
            "resourcePath": "/MY_PATH",
            "httpMethod": "POST",
            "extendedRequestId": "xxx=",
            "requestTime": "25/Jun/2024:14:54:00 +0000",
            "path": "/dev/MY_PATH",
            "accountId": "xxx",
            "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
            "stage": "dev",
            "domainPrefix": "xxx",
            "requestTimeEpoch": 1719327240217,
            "requestId": "xx",
            "identity": {
                "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
                "accountId": null,
                "cognitoIdentityId": null,
                "caller": null,
                "sourceIp": "51.198.135.75",
                "principalOrgId": null,
                "accessKey": null,
                "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
                "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
                "userArn": null,
                "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
                "user": null
            },
            "domainName": "xo92e4470h.execute-api.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com",
            "deploymentId": "sa27pp",
            "apiId": "xo92e4470h"
        },

I note that cognitoIdentityPoolId is null, however I am unsure of the relevance.
Can anyone shed any light on what I'm missing to expose the attributes of the calling user to the API that is being called?
I was epxecting to get an "authorizer" object in lambda requestContext logs, but none appears, even after setting cognito authorizer  in API Gateway.

The post method does not take a "headers" parameter how you would normally expect, headers instead goes as in as a key in the options object instead
post({
        apiName: MY_API_NAME,
        path: "/MY_PATH",
        options: { 
            body: params,
            headers
        },
    });

Thankfully a simple (albeit silly) mistake

The lambda request context authorizer property you are expecting comes from using lambda authorizers. When using the Cognito User Pool authorizer, you can grab the token from the Authorization header and decode it using a JWT library and access whatever attributes the token contains.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding something else! I've just done some testing and found that regardless of if I add the "Authorization" header in my request above, the request goes through. I don't quite understand why nothing is happening, I have deployed the change, created the authorizer and associated it with the resource in the API Gateway.
The Auth token I'm sending under "Authorization" is the value I get from "fetchAuthSession().tokens.idToken". Assuming this was appearing in the request headers in the api lambda, is this what I would decode for access to attributes?

Just a followup on this. I have found that it was issues with my deployment. However Now when I include the header as in the above code samples, I get an "Unauthorized" error. When I use the same token (id_token) in the Authorizer Test functionality it works fine! Same with sending it via POSTMAN. Not sure why it is unauthorized!

Well, that is progress! When setting your Authorization header are you setting it as a Bearer token? eg "Authorization: Bearer {{your-token}}"

Hi Patrick, yes I have tried it using the "Bearer" syntax as well to no avail:
```{"Authorization": "Bearer " + user_ID_Token"}``

If there is no sensitive data, would you be able to add screenshots from the API Gateway console of the Authorizer and then the Method request settings where the authorizer is set on the API?
